# JavaFX: HBox with a close button

Tags: java, button, javafx, hbox

**Is it possible to have a `HBox` with a close button (i.e. a child button with the purpose of removing the `HBox`)?** I am planning to implement it into something like this:

[image: See image here.]

I want to make a class of my own that inherits from the `HBox` class and has a close button already once it is instantiated. **The close button needs to remove the `HBox` from the parent of the `HBox`** (in this case, the `VBox` parent), **not hide it**. But I'm not sure if it is possible.

If it is possible, how should `setOnAction` of the close button be implemented?

Comment: you could use hbox.getParent() to access the parent VBox and use vbox.getChildren().remove(hbox); to remove yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure this is possible:

```
EventHandler<ActionEvent> handler = event -> {
    // get button that triggered the action
    Node n = (Node) event.getSource();

    // get node to remove
    Node p = n.getParent();

    // remove p from parent's child list
    ((Pane) p.getParent()).getChildren().remove(p);
};
Button button = new Button("x");
button.setOnAction(handler);
```

Note that the same instance of the event handler can be reused for multiple close buttons, since you get the button that was clicked from the event object.